# how to choose the correct version of android CTS

Tags: android, cts

i work for a phone vendor, our phone was based on Android 2.3.4_r1 GRJ22 , but when i ran the CTS , the OsVersionTest fails for the reason of not supporting 2.3.4 in test case.

how to choose the version of CTS?

Comment: is there anyone can answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

Probably way too late for what you need (I only really started serious use of CTS recently), but figured I give what bit of an answer I had anyway.

As I understand it (and I could be wrong), you can download CTS for a bunch of versions of Android at
http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html
I would think that the 2.3 build should work for you as I don't think minor versions prevent it from running (and that seems true in my tests).

From 4.0 on, CTS is in the Android Open Source code so you can build it yourself although I've had issues there (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400938/building-working-cts-for-user-build for example) and since you are on 2.3 you can't build it anyway.