# In Android, Build CTS vs Download CTS. What is the difference?

Tags: android, cts

we will shortly begin testing our Android port to a custom target board. As part of this test, we plan to execute the CTS. When researching the CTS, I came across [this page](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads) on Android which provides CTS test suite for download. It also comes with a script to run the test scripts. Whereas, there are plenty of tutorials [out there](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.in/2010/04/android-cts-compatibility-test-suite.html) and some [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824015/how-to-build-android-cts-and-how-to-add-and-run-your-test-case) which discuss how to build CTS from source.

My question is if CTS can be downloaded directly from Android site, in what scenarios would I need to build the CTS from source code?

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for instructions on how to build CTS. I only need to understand when to use downloaded CTS and when to build it.

Comment: Found this thread which mentions that 4.0 onwards it is possible to build CTS from source. But it does not explain when to use downloaded CTS and when to build.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225788/how-to-choose-the-correct-version-of-android-cts?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to build CTS from source code in case of:

- You have fail test cases in your running and you want to debug through the actual cts code by, such as adding more log on the particular test cases.
- You want to experiment new added test cases from upstream branch but not yet update on official cts-tradefed package.

Also I think you should have a look on on cts development project on aosp gerrit, so you would have more idea on how cts development is going on
https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/status:open+project:platform%252Fcts

Answer (score 0):

Google keeps releasing Android CTS suite very often . For your device to be called an Android device , you have to be compliant with the latest CTS for the particular android version you are using . So if any of the CTS test is not passing google will not accept it .

***When to use downloaded CTS*** :
   To excute the CTS always use the downloaded one .

***When to build CTS*** : 
   When a test case fails while running the downloaded one and you want to debug it , you can adds logs and build the CTS.

Answer (score 0):

"My question is if CTS can be downloaded directly from Android site"

**Yes, you can download directly from android site and RUN.**

"in what scenarios would I need to build the CTS from source code?"

**If test case failed and you are not getting root cause from logs and source code then you can add logs in cts test case code build it to find root cause.**